# excel index match need to return exact number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the following formula

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("\Files\"&INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,IF($E57="",NA(),MATCH($E57&"*",Sheet2!$A:$A,0))),$E57&".pdf"),"")
```

The lookup is

```
201693
  2016
```

Sheet 2 has this listed:

```
201693.pdf
```

It returns 201693 for both lookup. 2016 should be blank.

Comment: Remove this part of the formula: `&"*"`. You don't want a wildcard.

Comment: I need &"*" because the INDEX array has .pdf after the number.

Comment: I see. Try doing what I said but also matching to the array without the ".pdf", by changing the MATCH to `MATCH($E57,SUBSTITUTE(Sheet2!$A:$A,".pdf",""),0)`